# pathJS won't work - doesn't load any content

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, path.js

I tried to implement pathJS into my project, which is already using zurb.Foundation in combination with jQuery.

My JS is quite clean so far, so there shouldn't be any problems at all.

[I just created a fiddle to ease up testing http://jsfiddle.net/Vyuz5/](http://jsfiddle.net/Vyuz5/)

The Chrome Dev Tools point out this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined`

When I load the file via localhost, I just get the alert 'map' (immediately, without clicking anything).
As the documentation is quite minimal, I don't have any idea where I have these problems..

Comment: Is jQuery included in your page prior to PathJS? What version of each are you using?

Comment: yes. I included 1.9.1 via googles CDN server

Answer (score 0):

Alright.. fixed it.
I just had to remove the handler after the call:

```
Path.map("#/link1").to(function(){
  doNothing("it did it!");
  $('#loading').html('bazinga');
}).enter(doNothing('map_link1'));
```

to

```
Path.map("#/link1").to(function(){
  doNothing("it did it!");
  $('#loading').html('bazinga');
});
```

That's it.. whyever :)

[Revision 1](http://jsfiddle.net/danielwinter/Vyuz5/1/)